# Is there a free blogging service that I can setup to point to my domain/subdomain?

Tags: blog

I would like that because now I would have to extend my hosting plan to accomodate new domains, if I wanted to self host all my sites. My sites being very low traffic, the max domain count is the only thing I find limiting on my hosting plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to have a blog to use with your domain/subdomain you can use blogger by Google
- If you need a hosting that can support unlimited domain on the same space (unlimited) i suggest you to use Hostgator.

Answer (score 1):

**[tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/)** also supports custom domains.

It does look more like a ***social form*** of (photo)blogging or a ***twitter on steroids***, maybe, but many indie software people use it simply as a blog engine.

*No post comments* supported by default, but you can add them with **[disqus](http://www.disqus.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress.com supports user's hostnames also and allow any amout of separate  blogs per account